# unable to understand triggerHandler() method

Tags: jquery

I am not able to get following points of the `triggerHandler()` method:

> - While .`trigger()` will operate on all elements matched by the jQuery object, `.triggerHandler()` only affects the first matched element.
> - Events created with `.triggerHandler()` do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly, they do nothing.
> - Instead of returning the jQuery object (to allow chaining), `.triggerHandler()` returns whatever value was returned by the last handler it caused to be executed. If no handlers are triggered, it returns `undefined`

For more details see http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Comment: Do you want to know *why* `triggerHandler` behaves as described? The behaviour seems to be pretty clear but itself. If it's not for you, please add some explanation to each point about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is much improved performance for custom events that don't usually need event bubbling and being able
to call any event name safely without triggering native actions such as browser following links, resetting or submitting forms.

---

For `$(".item").trigger("click");`:

Unlike `.triggerHandler`, the event is triggered on all the elements selected with the `.item`- selector.

Unlike `.triggerHandler`, the event is triggered on all the parents, grandparents, grandgrandparents etc of all the elements
with `.item`-selector.

Unlike `.triggerHandler`, you can continue chaining after `.trigger()` e.g. you can do `$(".item").trigger("click").addClass("clicked");`

With the following DOM tree, I mark with X where the `"click"`- event is triggered when `$(".item").trigger("click");` is called:

```
<body X>
    <div class="container" X>
        <ul X>
            <li class="item" X>
            <li class="item" X>
            <li class="item" X>
            <li class="item" X>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here's the same with `$(".item").triggerHandler("click");`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="item" X>
            <li class="item">
            <li class="item">
            <li class="item">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```